# Inputing samples from a dataframe into an ARMA model and getting 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.'

Tags: python, dataframe, statsmodels

I have an 8 by 7 dataframe ‘selected_parameters’ as following

[image: selected_parameters_dataframe]

ar_params and ma_params corresponds to the evaluated parameters of an ARMA model on a time series.

I then select randomly one parameter from ar_params and ma_params:

```
ar_sample = selected_parameters['ar_params'].sample(1)
ma_sample = selected_parameters['ma_params'].sample(1)
```

And modify them as follow in order to be then used to generate time series with an ARMA process, following the explanations at the end of this page

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_process.arma_generate_sample.html

```
ar_sample_array = np.r_[1, -ar_sample]
ma_sample_array = np.r_[1, ma_sample]

y = arma_generate_sample(ar_sample_array, ma_sample_array, nsample=100, scale=0.1)
plt.plot(y)
```

Everything works well IF we did select a set of ar_params and ma_params including only ONE value.

If at the random selection stage, we did select a set with two or more values I receive the following error message.

```
‘ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.’
```

When printing the values of ar_sample_array and ma_sample_array

```
print(ar_sample_array)
print(ma_sample_array)
```

I get the following output

```
[1 array([-1.01,  0.01])]
[1 array([-0.76,  0.03])]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the params must but only one array, not one array with other array inside. I think this would work:

```
ar_sample_array = [1].append(-ar_sample)
ma_sample_array = [1].append(ma_sample)
```

Comment: When running 

print(ar_sample_array)
print(ma_sample_array)

it returns

None
None